# How can I convert IP address to integer before saving to database

Tags: php, mysql

I've read in some posts ,IP address can convert and save as integer in mysql db . Can anybody show with examples ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to convert them to integers?

Comment: How sould the integer look like? Simply the dots removed or some other transformation?

Comment: INT will  go down to only 4 bytes of space than varchar

Comment: Make sure you use a BIGINT column and not an INT.  The top end of the IP address space will hit a ceiling if you use INT.  If I remember correctly, the ceiling is in Mexico.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ip2long()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Answer (score 6):

```
ip2long()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Since you say you want to use this with a MySQL database, use these two functions to convert from and to numbers compatible to MySQLs INET_ATON and INET_NTOA.

```
<?php
    function convertIpToString($ip)
    {
        $long = 4294967295 - ($ip - 1);
        return long2ip(-$long);
    }
    function convertIpToLong($ip)
    {
        return sprintf("%u", ip2long($ip));
    }
?>
```

Refer to MySQL functions:

```
INET_ATON()     -- Return the numeric value of an IP address
INET_NTOA()     -- Return the IP address from a numeric value
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

Answer (score 1):

[ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php)    `$ip = ip2long($ip);`

[check this link too](http://daipratt.co.uk/mysql-store-ip-address/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ip2long() for converting to int

```
$Db_ip=ip2long("127.0.0.1");
```

To get ip address

```
$ip = long2ip($Db_ip); // "127.0.0.1"
```